# A link is broken within a list.

Tags: support, status-completed

In a recent [answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13927/secret-of-making-maple-candy-texture), I made a list with the `<ul>` and `<li>` tags, as always. When I placed a link in one of the answers, it was broken, it looked like that:`[description text][1]`.

What did I do wrong? How to correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix HTML with [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). The proper way to make an unordered list in Markdown is to use either '*', '-', or '+' like so:

- foo
- bar
- baz

  - biff

    - bam
    - boop

Ordered lists are done similarly by using the digit `1`.

1. Foo
2. Bar

   1. Biff
   2. Bam
3. Boop

This is also accessible using the toolbar directly above the edit window.